# Can Kannel send long MT using SAR_* parameters?

Tags: kannel

Is it possible to let Kannel send long sms-mt using TLV SAR_* parameters and not using UDH in v1.4.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, TLV support was added in v1.5.0, it cannot be done in 1.4.3.